# Longest monotonically decreasing subsequence, with no consecutive elements included

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

for example:

```
s = <6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1>, s1 = <6, 4, 1>, s2 = <5, 2>, s3 = <5, 3, 2>
```

Given `s` as a sequence, `s1` and `s2` are the valid subsequences to be considered, but `s3` is not because it contains a consecutive elements 3 and 2.

How do you find a longest such a subsequence so that it is monotonically decreasing in `O(n^2)`

I am aware of the version of the question that contains monotonic increase/ decrease.

But the additional condition here makes it difficult.

A trivial solution would be to start at `i = n'th` element as well as at `j = (n-1)'th` element, solve as if solving for longest monotonically decreasing subsequence with consideration that next element is at `(i-2)'th` and `(j-2)'th` respectively and compare the length of two at the end. This will still give the `O(n^2)`, but does seem way too trivial.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Your title says monotonically decreasing, but your body says monotonically non-decreasing. What are you looking for?

Comment: oops.. corrected a typo!

Comment: Your examples aren't monotonically decreasing, though.

Comment: ...are you sure you know what "decrease" means? And why would "too trivial" be a reason to reject an algorithm that you think works?

Comment: And why are you going for O(n^2) when standard algorithms for the longest increasing subsequence problem achieve O(n log n)?

Comment: @user2357112, the question was asked in the interview. It was for embedded engineer's position, and the discussion flowed into arguments that we cannot use hashmaps.

Comment: @user2357112, not rejecting it, but interviewer kept saying there exists a better solution. This is what I could come up with at the interview as well as after thinking about it for a long time. So I am curious what could be done.

Comment: How about you finding another series of a(n+1)-a(n) and then check for the current series for the positive numbers including 0 (since your requirement is not `strictly monotonically decreasing`) and then count the consecutive positive numbers with indices in two variables: beginning of highest number of consecutive positive numbers and beginning of current. I havent myself tried but I guess it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
D[i] = max { D[j] + 1 | a[i] < a[j], j < i + 1 } U {1}
```

Explanation: for each element `a[i]`, your Dynamic Programming (DP) checks for all numbers that are before it and with lower value, but not adjacent - if the new number can be used to extend the best sequence. In addition, you have the option to start a new sequence (that's when the {1} comes to play).

Example:
S = <6, 0, 5, 8, 4, 7, 6 >

```
D[1] = max { 1 } = 1  // sequence = <6>
D[2] = max {1} = 1  // sequence = <0>
D[3] = max {1, D[0] + 1 } = 2  // sequence = <6, 5>
D[4] = max {1} = 1  // sequence = <8>
D[5] = max{D[3] + 1, D[1] + 1, 1} = 3 // sequence = <6, 5, 4>
D[6] = max{D[4] + 1, 1} = 2  // sequence = <8, 7>
D[7] = max{D[4] + 1, 1} = 2  // sequence = <8, 6>
```

The algorithm runs in `O(n^2)`, since calculating `D[i]` takes `O(i)` time. From sum of arithmetic progression, this sums to `O(n^2)` to calculate all.

When you are done calculating all `D[.]`,  you iterate through all of them, and find the maximal value. This is done in linear time.